# PHP symfony 2.x: How to authenticate against a web-service by providing username and password?

Tags: php, web-services, security, symfony, authentication

I have a very big problem with symfony 2.x. I need to authenticate against a web-service by passing the username and the password to this web-service.

The standard way and any other implementation of the security layer and UserProvider i've seen retrieve the user from the user repository by passing only the username to the repository (in my case the web-service). Symfony assumes that the repository returns the user for the provided username and that this user contains the password (encrypted). Then the authentication of the user is done by comparing the password from the login form with the password that's returned with the user object (or whatever you want to validate in this place). According to the result of this validation access is granted or denied.

What I need – and I think it's a common requirement – is passing the username and the password to the repository (the web-service) and let the repository decide if this credentials belong to a valid user or not. This means whenever symfony receives a user object from the repository the user is authenticated and authentication fails when the user repository returns anything else (preferably an error-object).

But as far as the security layer of symfony is very complex and the complete authentication process relies on the interface method `loadUserByUsername` I really have no idea how to implement my own UserProvider that matches my requirement without replacing the whole security layer with something that implements some kind of `loadUserByUsernameAndPassword`.

Does anyone has a solution or a step by step tutorial for this task.

Comment: What is wrong with `loadUserByUsername`? That's the perfect time to check if a given user has permissions or not to your route or whatever before authenticating it. You just get the user from the database and compare his roles with the requirements. If the user does not match, you just return null.

Comment: As I wrote in my question I need to provide username and password to the web-service because the service does require this. So this is not my decision but a requirement and `loadUserByUsername` (which is the method that is intended to retrieve the user from the repository) only takes the username as argument and therefore is only able to pass the username to the web-service. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Looks like you need a custom authentication provider: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

Comment: Yes, i have concern too. 
No web service will provide password & other data based only on only username. 

Is there any solution for this? or how to i get login form password value in loadUserByUsername() function ?

Comment: I solved the problem by working around the loadUserByUsername()-method. I now provide username and password as one string separated by a special delimiter. Within this method I split the username and password to their original values and then send the request to the webservice. It's a little bit strange but at least it works reliable and currently I don't see any drawbacks.